# In Wordpress website First customer Subscribe then place a free order. How can I do?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscription

I want a WordPress website where Customer first subscribe then place an free order. There will be only one product. Suppose there should be 3 packages - Silver, Gold, Diamond. In silver packages customer can place 10 free orders of that product, In gold 20 and in Diamond 30. Besides Woocommerce which other plugins should I use for that purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You should search membership or subscription plugin instead of order plugin.

There are multiple plugins available where you can define your custom membership package and set membership/subscription price accordingly.

Few are :

https://yithemes.com/themes/plugins/yith-woocommerce-subscription/

https://wpforms.com/best-wordpress-membership-plugins-compared/

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/orders/